# Efficient way to rebuild a dictionary of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dictionary, structure

I have a dictionary that is filled with multiple dataframes. Now I am searching for an efficient way for changing the key structure, but the solution I have found is rather slow when more dataframes / bigger dataframes are involved. Thats why I wanted to ask if anyone might know a more convenient / efficient / faster way or approach than mine. So first, I created this example to show where I initially started:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# assign keys to dic
teams = ["Arsenal", "Chelsea", "Manchester United"]
dic_teams = {}

# fill dic with random entries
for t1 in teams:

    dic_teams[t1] = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range("20180101", periods=30), 
                                  'Goals': pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,5, size = 30)),
                                  'Chances': pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,15, size = 30)),
                                  'Fouls': pd.Series(np.random.randint(0, 20, size = 30)),
                                  'Offside': pd.Series(np.random.randint(0, 10, size = 30))})

    dic_teams[t1] = dic_teams[t1].set_index('date')
    dic_teams[t1].index.name = None
```

Now I basically have a dictionary where every key is a team, which means I have a dataframe for every team with information on their game performance over time. Now I would prefer to change this particular dictionary so I get a structure where the key is the date, instead of a team. This would mean that I have a dataframe for every date, which is filled with the performance of each team on that date. I managed to do that using the following code, which works but is really slow once I add more teams and performance factors:

```
# prepare lists for looping
dates = dic_teams["Arsenal"].index.to_list()
perf = dic_teams["Arsenal"].columns.to_list()
dic_dates = {}

# new structure where key = date
for d in dates:
    dic_dates[d] = pd.DataFrame(index = teams, columns = perf)

    for t2 in teams:
        dic_dates[d].loc[t2] = dic_teams[t2].loc[d]
```

Because I am using a nested loop, the restructuring of my dictionary is slow. Does anyone have an idea how I could improve the second piece of code? I'm not necessarily searching just for a solution, also for a logic or idea how to do better.

Thanks in advance, any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Creating a Pandas dataframes the way you do is (strangely) awfully slow, as well as direct indexing*.

Copying a dataframe is surprisingly quite fast. Thus you can use an empty reference dataframe copied multiple times. Here is the code:

```py
dates = dic_teams["Arsenal"].index.to_list()
perf = dic_teams["Arsenal"].columns.to_list()
zygote = pd.DataFrame(index = teams, columns = perf)
dic_dates = {}

# new structure where key = date
for d in dates:
    dic_dates[d] = zygote.copy()

    for t2 in teams:
        dic_dates[d].loc[t2] = dic_teams[t2].loc[d]
```

This is about 2 times faster than the reference on my machine.

Overcoming the slow dataframe direct indexing is tricky. We can use numpy to do that. Indeed, we can convert the dataframe to a 3D numpy array, use numpy to perform the transposition, and finally convert the slices into dataframes again. Note that this approach assumes that *all values are integers and that the input dataframe are well structured*.

Here is the final implementation:

```py
dates = dic_teams["Arsenal"].index.to_list()
perf = dic_teams["Arsenal"].columns.to_list()
dic_dates = {}

# Create a numpy array from Pandas dataframes
# Assume the order of the `dates` and `perf` indices are the same in all dataframe (and their order)
full = np.empty(shape=(len(teams), len(dates), len(perf)), dtype=int)
for tId,tName in enumerate(teams):
    full[tId,:,:] = dic_teams[tName].to_numpy()

# New structure where key = date, created from the numpy array
for dId,dName in enumerate(dates):
    dic_dates[dName] = pd.DataFrame({pName: full[:,dId,pId] for pId,pName in enumerate(perf)}, index = teams)
```

This implementation is *6.4 times faster* than the reference on my machine. Note that about 75% of the time is sadly spent in the `pd.DataFrame` calls. Thus, if you want a faster code, *use a basic 3D numpy array*!

Comment: Dear Jerome, thanks a lot for your answer. I tried the copy method on my real code, and it did enhance the performance! I would like to try the numpy method, but unfortunately my dataframes do not have integers, but float numbers. Is it also possible to change into (and out again) of such a numpy array structure while using float numbers?

Comment: @Sanoj Yes, you can use `dtype=float` rather than `dtype=int`. This means that all value will be of type float (ie. no string).

Comment: @ Jerome I'm absolutely blown away after implementing your approach in my code. Because I am dealing with such a large dictionary, it lowered the calculation time from 10 mintues to 30 seconds. I really need to make the switch to work more with numpy arrays instead of dataframes.